# Api Call Schedule - .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple table in database, which looks like this:

`|---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |Id | Price | StartsAt            | EndsAt              |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 24.95 | 2018-13-10 10:15:00 | 2018-13-10 11:00:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 25.00 | 2018-13-10 11:00:00 | 2018-13-10 12:15:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 26.00 | 2018-13-10 12:15:00 | 2018-13-10 13:10:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 27.95 | 2018-13-10 13:10:00 | 2018-13-10 15:00:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 28.15 | 2018-13-10 15:00:00 | 2018-13-10 19:00:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
 |1  | 29.10 | 2018-13-10 19:00:00 | 2018-13-10 00:00:00 |
 |---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|`

Then, i need to make a post in another application, when the StartsAt Hour/Day comes.

I've googled for schedule messages in RabbitMq, that will appear on rabbit queue at his time.

I've googled also, to schedule Api Calls with [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io).

Which the best practice to work with api call schedules?

Comment: Having never used these technologies yet myself (we will however be using both Rabbit/Kafka and Hangfire in our new API), I am under the impression you should use both. Hangfire is good for scheduling units of work, whereas Rabbit or any queueing system is good for guaranteeing message delivery.

Comment: “Which Is Best” is much different than “what will work”. Also depends on if your taking advantage of public cloud like azure or aws, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using hangfire, but it also can be solved with Kafka.

The Correct answer is "It depends on your scenario".